# SageMaker PyTorchModel passing custom variables

Tags: pytorch, amazon-sagemaker, keyword-argument

When deploying a model with SageMaker through the `PyTorchModel` class, is it possible to pass a custom environmental variable or kwargs?

I'd like to be able to switch the functionality of the serving code via a custom argument rather than needing to write multiple `serve.py` to handle different training model export methods.

```
model = PyTorchModel(name='my_model',
                     model_data=estimator.model_data,
                     role=role,
                     framework_version='1.0.0',
                     entry_point='serve.py',
                     source_dir='src',
                     sagemaker_session=sess,
                     predictor_cls=ImagePredictor,
                     <custom_argument?>
                    )
```

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using the `env` parameter in your `PyTorchModel` ? (cf. https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/model.html#sagemaker.model.Model)

```
model = PyTorchModel(name='my_model',
                     model_data=estimator.model_data,
                     role=role,
                     framework_version='1.0.0',
                     entry_point='serve.py',
                     source_dir='src',
                     sagemaker_session=sess,
                     predictor_cls=ImagePredictor,
                     env={'ENV_VALUE': 'val'}
                    )
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work (from a trained `estimator` or from a `model`, with the high-level [Python SDK](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/))

```
model.deploy(
    initial_instance_count=1, 
    instance_type='ml.m5.xlarge',
    env={'MY_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE':'value'})
```

Comment: with a `PyTorchModel` I get `TypeError: deploy() got an unexpected keyword argument 'env'`